# svg in symbol tags are taking spaces in the bottom

Tags: html, css, svg, symbols

I have stacked many svg codes in symbol tags at the bottom of all my codes like--

```
<svg>
    <symbol id attributes>
        svg codes
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

and using these svgs up in use tags wherever necessary, like--

```
<svg>
    <use href="#id"></use>
</svg>
```

I am doing this to have a cleaner code cause all the svgs were making my code crowded.

But these codes residing at bottom I thought isn't showing at all, but actually these codes are taking there space at the bottom of the website.

How do I fix it?

Comment: you can put all the symbols in the same svg element and give the svg element width="0" height="0"

Answer (score 1):

The `SVG` that contains all the symbols referenced in  the page should be hidden, so apply a `display: none`

Comment: Thanks, tried to display:none the symbol tags, but it doesn’t work, then created a div containing all the svgs, then display:noned that div. It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Put all your SVG codes into a separate div with its own class, then set the CSS for that class to display:none.